# Error in "random forest" from the Caret Package

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I am using R-studio (Version 0.98.994.) in a machine running OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite) to apply a „random forest“ from the Caret Package. Here is my code:

```
library(caret)
data(iris)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=iris$Species, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
training <- iris[inTrain,]
testing <- iris[-inTrain,]

# Use o Random Forest do CARET
modFit <- train(Species ~ ., data=training, method="rf", prox=TRUE)
modFit
```

And Here is the Error:

```
Error in checkInstall(models$library) : 
Calls: <Anonymous> ... train.formula -> train -> train.default -> checkInstall
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `randomForest` library. It is one of the suggested libraries in `caret` and where the `rf` method comes from. After you install it it should work fine like this:

```
library(randomForest)
library(caret)

data(iris)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=iris$Species, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
training <- iris[inTrain,]
testing <- iris[-inTrain,]

# Use o Random Forest do CARET
modFit <- train(Species ~ ., data=training, method="rf", prox=TRUE)
modFit
```

Output:

```
> modFit
Random Forest 

105 samples
  4 predictor
  3 classes: 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 

Summary of sample sizes: 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD
  2     0.949     0.923  0.0290       0.0436  
  3     0.953     0.929  0.0305       0.0460  
  4     0.948     0.921  0.0297       0.0447  

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 3.
```

Comment: Hi LyzandeR thanks for the information. I've clicked the green arrow. Cool!

Comment: :) Thanks! Happy asking and answering !!